# Permission denied - Cpanel - Git Version Control (Private repo)

Tags: gitlab, cpanel

Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended: Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I generate new ssh key on Cpanel without password, and upload id_rsa.pub on my own gitlab repo, but when i try to clone repo from my own gitlab to cpanel it's not working :/

Someone can help? Thanks

Comment: We will need more information to help. Do other SSH keys work? Can you create an SSH keypair on your workstation, add the public key to GitLab, and clone successfully? This information will help narrow down whether the issue is with GitLab or CPanel.

Comment: Yes, i created SSH keypair on my server, and add the public key to Gitlab, but i cannot clone because of permission denied. I tought maybe it's because of my private gitlab server, but i tried also with bitbucket and permission denied error again. Should my website need to be visible from outside, because i created on whm new account with domain which doesn't exist just for try does Git Control on cpanel works?

Comment: The other step I mentioned above will be helpful - Can you create an SSH keypair on your workstation, add the public key to GitLab, and clone successfully from your workstation?

To create a keypair locally, follow instructions at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html.

Comment: Yea, i already did that from my Git Bash and when i type ssh -T git@myserver.com it's work, Welcome to Gitlab message, and can clone the project too.

Comment: OK. This means it's a problem with CPanel and how it uses SSH then. As long as you're putting the public key from CPanel into GitLab, that's the only explanation I can come up with. SSH from other hosts works fine.

Comment: What happened now...when i tried "ssh -T git@example.com" from terminal in Cpanel it's pass and asked me for password, but when i tried to create repo (clone from gitlab) it says permission denied, after that, when i tried again "ssh -T git@example.com" from terminal in Cpanel here is error: ssh: connect to host git.example.com port 22: Connection refused

Comment: The first two errors make sense but the last one does not. Unfortunately, this seems like a CPanel issue rather than GitLab. I have no experience with CPanel

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I am having the same problems

Comment: Ok, solved. Cpanel didn't ask for a password while my id_rsa.pub file did, so it failed. It works with a rsa public key that doesn't require a password. Not sure if this is a good solution, but I have individuate the problem at least.